Accessing memory byte by byte
I have been learning about pointers in C/C++ since quite few days and wanted to execute the following code.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    int x = 1025;
    int *p = &x;
    char* myp = (char*) p;
    cout << *myp << endl;
    return 0;
}

This code compiles and runs perfectly except that the output is some weird character (in VS code) and blank in terminal.
As far as I understand pointers, they store address of a particular variable. We specify the data type of the pointer so that it reads that many bytes from that particular memory address. So 1025 should have been stored as 00000000 00000000 00000100 00000001 with the address of 00000001 stored in pointer p. When I typecast the pointer to a character pointer then on dereferencing the program should read only one byte from the memory location. For this reason, I expected an output of 1.
This program runs perfectly in C, however gives wrong output in C++. What is the fallacy in this logic/code?

char is an integer type, but it is used for characters, hence << does not print its integer value, but the corresponding character.

"This program runs perfectly in C" no it doesnt. The code is C++. Please dont mix the tags unless the question is about interoperation of the two languages. In your code the answer is about how operator<< treats chars. In C there is no such operator. Details matter. In C the situation would be similar but not the same. C and C++ are two different languages.

See cout not printing unsigned char and Printing chars as Integers and cout << with char* argument prints string, not pointer value and How to output a character as an integer through cout?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Updated the links.

If you want the actual C representation it would be printf("%c\n", *myp). Which like the C++ code prints the value as a character.

On a different note, whenever you feel the need to do a C-style explicit conversion (the cast you do) then it's usually a red flag that you're probably doing something wrong.

Instead of using char, use uint8_t or int8_t.  The char type can be signed, unsigned or compiler defined.

Interesting fun fact. When examined as bits in memory you're a lot more likely to see 00000001 00000100 00000000 00000000 than 00000000 00000000 00000100 00000001 due to little endian byte order

The overloaded << operator for cout is receiving a char as its argument, and as a result it is printing the character associated with the value.
So for example, assuming ASCII, if the value given was 65 it would print A.
You need to cast the value to type int so the proper overload is applied:
cout << static_cast<int>(*myp) << endl;


Since you're printing a char value, the output will be converted to ascii.
To print it as a number, try casting it to a number type before printing:
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    int x = 1025;
    int *p = &x;
    char* myp = (char*) p;
    std::cout << static_cast<short>(*myp) << endl;
    return 0;
}

